# change image on click of button in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton, uiimage

i draged 3 button in my .xib file (btn1,btn2,btn3 respectively) and initially i given default image to them, first.png

now when user clicks on btn1, image of btn1 should change from first.png to second.png..

and when user selects on btn2, image of btn2 should change from first.png to second.png, and also change image of btn1 to default again first.png, so that user came to know he has clicked 2nd button.

**how should i do this ?**

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Comment: you want to implement radio button type in iphone?

Comment: yes i want to implement like radio button ...

Answer (score 3):

You have to set button action method code

```
-(IBAction)btnClked:(id)sender
{
  [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btn3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

  [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


    @interface CustomRadioButton : UIButton {

    }

    @end


#import "CustomRadioButton.h"


@implementation CustomRadioButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Set the refresh icon as the button's image
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        // When the button is pressed, draw to button with less opacity.
        self.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

inside the Implement file of the viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (int i=1;i<=2;i++){

        CustomRadioButton *Radiobutton = [CustomRadioButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        Radiobutton = [[CustomRadioButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,50*i, 30, 30)];

        [Radiobutton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        Radiobutton.tag=i;

        [self.view addSubview:Radiobutton];

        }

}


    - (IBAction)checkboxButton:(UIButton *)button{

        for (UIButton *Radiobutton in [self.view subviews]) {
            if ([Radiobutton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && ![Radiobutton isEqual:button]) {
                [Radiobutton setSelected:NO];
            }
        }
        if (!button.selected) {
            button.selected = !button.selected;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the images in your button call method like:

```
BOOL first;
-(void)firstBtnPressed
   {
   if(first == YES){
   [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   first = NO;
   }
   else
   {
    first = YES;
    [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
}
```