# change image on click of UIButton in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change image on click of button in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786065/change-image-on-click-of-button-in-objective-c)

i draged 3 button in my .xib file and initially i given default image to them using property window as first.png.

i don't know name of my buttons, because i created button by dragging, i want to know what will be the name of my button ?

now when user clicks on firstButton, image of button should change from first.png to second.png..

and when user selects on 2nd button, image of button2 should change from first.png to second.png, and also change image of 1st button to default again first.png, so that user came to know he has clicked 2nd button.

in short i want to implement like radio button.

**how should i do this ?**

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Comment: are you new in iPhone development? how can you know the name of buttons without referencing them. you have to define them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ankit explian you this can done in multi ways

I suppose you have created two button `add_btn`, `requestBtn` with Interface Builder.

Now you need to set the connection (Event, outlet) for both button.

I think you have knowledge so, I will not explain here how to set button (control) connection (Event, outlet) via inteface builder.

For example: `add_btn` connected to `AddFriends` methods and `requestBtn` with `getFriendRequest`.

Now you can change the Image of Button As

```
#pragma mark change Image of first Button
-(void)AddFriends:(UIButton*)sender{       
    [add_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cliked1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [requestBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unCliked2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
}

#pragma mark change Image of second Button
-(void)getFriendRequest:(UIButton*)sender{
    [add_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unCliked1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [requestBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cliked2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways in which you can do this..
here are a couple of those..

1. You can give name to these buttons using IBOutlets and determine which button sent the message.
2. You can determine by tag on buttons which can be edited on the xib itself and you can determine which button sent the message using the tag properties..